# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' --- error-guard.js

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest, react-native-testing-library

jest config is package json

`"jest": {     "preset": "react-native",     "setupFiles": [       "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"     ],     "collectCoverage": true,     "transform": {       "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$": "ts-jest"     },     "transformIgnorePatterns": [       "/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/).*/"     ]   },`

babel config is babel.config.js

`module.exports = {   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],   plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], };` 
[image: error message]

I tried to search for it on google but nothing similar. I managed to get rid of the error with a fix for another error but then the "other" error came and I already had the fix.
Do you guys encountered this issue, or do you have any idea how to solve it?

I also tried to create some simple tests and jest is working, but when I use it on the whole app I get this error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed something similar by adding this to jest.config.js

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
     "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-modal|react-native-config|react-native-animatable|@balance-inc)/)"
  ]
```